# How to generate multiple plots by clicking a single plot for more information using clickable python events

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am in the process of developing an application which can generate a 2nd plot by clicking data point in the 1st plot. I am using events to accomplish this.

Question:

1. How to generate a 3rd plot by clicking a 2nd plot data point? Is it possible to accomplish to this?
2. How to generate a simpler 3 layer synthetic data?

Code I have so far:

```
"""
compute the mean and stddev of 100 data sets and plot mean vs stddev.
When you click on one of the mu, sigma points, plot the raw data from
the dataset that generated the mean and stddev
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.random.rand(100, 1000)
xs = np.mean(X, axis=1)
ys = np.std(X, axis=1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(211)
bx = fig.add_subplot(212)

# ax.set_title('click on point to plot time series')
# bx.set_title('click on point to plot time series')


line, = ax.plot(xs, ys, 'bs', picker=5)  # 5 points tolerance
line1, = bx.plot(xs, ys, 'bo', picker=5)  # 5 points tolerance

def onpick(event):

    if event.artist!=line: return True

    N = len(event.ind)
    if not N: return True


    figi = plt.figure()
    for subplotnum, dataind in enumerate(event.ind):

        ax = figi.add_subplot(N,1,subplotnum+1)
        ax.plot(X[dataind])
        ax.text(0.05, 0.9, 'mu=%1.3f\nsigma=%1.3f'%(xs[dataind], ys[dataind]),
                transform=ax.transAxes, va='top')
        ax.set_ylim(-0.5, 1.5)

        bx = figi.add_subplot(N,1,subplotnum+1)
        bx.plot(X[dataind])
        bx.text(0.05, 0.9, 'mu=%1.3f\nsigma=%1.3f'%(xs[dataind], ys[dataind]),
                transform=ax.transAxes, va='top')
        bx.set_ylim(-0.5, 1.5)

    figi.show()
    return True

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```

[image: 1st plot]

By clicking data points on the first plot, 2nd plot will be generated.

[image: 2nd plot]

Now expectations are to generate a 3rd plot clicking the 2nd plot data point.

[I have researched on this, but I am not successful :-( :-(](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

If my approach is wrong, please do suggest the any other alternative.

Comment: Why not just install the same type of pick event on the second canvas?

Comment: @tcaswell Thank you. I really appreciate any example code snippet for this

Comment: I would refer you back to the code snippet in your question.  Just do not close over `line`.

Comment: If I do not close over line, result is not as expected and could you please explain bit more.

Answer (score 5):

#### synthetic 3 level data

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# data source
data_bucket = {}

# l1: randn
# l2: sum(l1)
# l3: sum(l2)


# generate some 3 layer synthetic data
N = 1000
l1_count = 50
l2_count = 50
l3_count = 2
x = np.arange(N)
for j in range(l3_count):
    l3 = []
    for k in range(l2_count):
        l2 = []
        for m in range(l1_count):
            l1 = data_bucket[(j, k, m)] = np.random.randn(N)
            l2.append(np.sum(l1))
        l2 = data_bucket[(j, k)] = np.asarray(l2)
        l3.append(np.sum(l2))
    data_bucket[(j, )] = np.asarary(l3)
```

#### The picker function

```
# only hase to close over the data
def picker(event):
    print(event.artist.get_gid())
    print(event.ind)
    # some function to generate next data key from gid + index
    k = event.artist.get_gid() + tuple(event.ind)
    try:
        next_data = data_bucket[k]
    except KeyError:
        print("no generations of data left")
        return
    # make the previous generation of plot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    # can use the key here to dispatch to different plotting functions
    ax.plot(next_data, gid=k, picker=5, ls='-')
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', picker)
```

#### Initial plot

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for k in range(l3_count):
    k = (k, )
    ax.plot(data_bucket[k], gid=k, picker=5, ls='', marker='o')
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', picker)
```

The tricky part of this managing the mapping between the data in the 'current' figure and the next layer of data.  All mpl artists have a `gid` attribute which can be used to uniquely identify them so here I use that + the index to generate keys into a dictionary which are tuples of integers of varying length.  This was just the first thing that popped into my head when trying to make synthetic 3-layer data.  In principle any keying system that uses the gid of the picked artist + the index in that line -> next layer of data will work.

You can then use the same picker function for all of your figures and it only needs to close over the data source.  All of this could (should?) be rolled up into a single class.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But still m not able figure out where is the problem with my code. So I there any simple way to provide synthetic 3 layer data. Now it is difficult to construct of 3 layer synthetic data for my data.

Comment: I have the simplest version of 3 level data I could come up with in the example.  Exactly what the layout of your real data is is presumably driven by your actual use case.

Comment: This means, you will update a new answer, Sorry I didn't get fully.